# Condition for equal or lower

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I've got this:

```
    {if $next_bid_amount > $bid}
            <br />
            <p>
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    The lowest possible next bid is {$meta.currency_sign}{$next_bid_amount|number_format}. Please bid this amount or higher.
                </div>
            </p>
            <br />
            {/if}
```

But it only works when I place a bid that is higher than the current value, how can I add the condition that it will allow me to place a bid equal OR higher than the current value?

Comment: Use the `>=` operator?

Comment: `>=`... these are basic mathematical operators, and [all documented](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 0):

it's written this way:  `>=` ..

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `>=` instead of `=`

`{if $next_bid_amount >= $bid} <br /> <p> <div class="alert alert-danger"> The lowest possible next bid is {$meta.currency_sign}{$next_bid_amount|number_format}. Please bid this amount or higher. </div> </p> <br /> {/if}`

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this,

```
$next_bid_amount >= $bid
```